# Obtaining the time of another binary execution C

Tags: c, time

I'm new here. I'm been trying to get the time of execution of a given binary (may or may not have been developed/compiled by myself. I got this `getTime()` function from [here](http://pizzachili.dcc.uchile.cl/utils/run_queries.c)!.

I wrote a little program to call another program and determine the time it took the second one to execute, but I haven't obtained the expected results. The program just exits almost right away and the output is a very small amount of time (even when I execute programs that are really time intensve)

**This is program I wrote.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h> // for pid_t 
#include <sys/wait.h> // for wait 

double getTime (void);
char**  argsCollect(int total, int from, char* source[]);
char*   newString(int len);
void freeCollected(char **collection, int len);
static double Load_time;

int main(int ac, char *av[]){

    char **my_args = argsCollect(ac, 2, av);

    Load_time = getTime ();
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid==0) { // child process 
        execv(av[1], my_args);
            exit(127); // only if execv fails 
    }
    else { /* pid!=0; parent process */
            int finished = waitpid(pid,0,0); // wait for child to exit      

        Load_time = getTime() - Load_time;
        printf("Finished child: %d, Tiempo: %f\n", finished, Load_time);    

        freeCollected(my_args, (ac - 1));
    }

    return 0;
}

double getTime (void){
    double usertime, systime;
    struct rusage usage;

    getrusage (RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);

    usertime = (double) usage.ru_utime.tv_sec +
        (double) usage.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

    systime = (double) usage.ru_stime.tv_sec +
        (double) usage.ru_stime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

    return (usertime + systime);
}

char** argsCollect(int total, int from, char* source[]){
    int collect = total - from;
    int i;

    char** mem_dest = (char**)malloc((collect) * sizeof(char*));

    for(i = from; i < total; i++){
        mem_dest[i-from] = newString(strlen(source[i]));
        strcpy(mem_dest[i-from], source[i]);
    }   

    return mem_dest;
}

char* newString(int len){
    char *new_string = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));

    return new_string;
}

void freeCollected(char **collection, int len){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        free(collection[i]);
    }
    free(collection);
}
```

**And I tested the `getTime()` function with this piece of code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

double getTime (void);
static double Load_time;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int max = 1000000000;
    int j = 0;  

    Load_time = getTime ();

    for(i = 0; i < max; i++){   // This is 
        j++;        // just to
    }           // do something

    Load_time = getTime () - Load_time;
    printf("time: %.2f, j: %d\n", Load_time, j);

    return 0;
}

double getTime (void){
    double usertime, systime;
    struct rusage usage;

    getrusage (RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);

    usertime = (double) usage.ru_utime.tv_sec +
        (double) usage.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

    systime = (double) usage.ru_stime.tv_sec +
        (double) usage.ru_stime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

    return (usertime + systime);
}
```

I'd really appreciate insight on how to make this work properly and about what about I'm doing wrong. 
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: For one thing you are calling `waitpid` wrong.  The second parameter is an output parameter; you need to pass in a pointer to an `int` that gets the status placed into it.  But don't bother with that, just use `wait`.

Comment: I actually got that `waitpid` usage from this site. I had tried several ways of doing it, that's just the one I was using at the moment.

Comment: I tried not forking, and it does not work. Actually in the [documentation of `exec` family functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv), it says that it replaces the current process image with a new process image.

Comment: Have you checked that your `execv` is working?

Comment: I've checked that. I'm actually calling a compressor (snappy) and the output files are the same as they are if I just execute the compressor by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record. How I solved this issue after 2 weeks.

I modified the `double getTime(void)` function into `double getTime(int who)` function, which is described in the following adaptation of the initial piece of code.

**New Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h> // for pid_t 
#include <sys/wait.h> // for wait 

double getTime (int who);
static double Load_time;

int main(int ac, char *av[]){
    int status;

    Load_time = getTime(RUSAGE_SELF);
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid==0) { // child process 
        execv(av[1], &av[2]);
            exit(127); // only if execv fails 
    }
    else { /* pid!=0; parent process */
            int finished = waitpid(pid,&status,0); // wait for child to exit      

        Load_time = getTime(RUSAGE_CHILDREN) - Load_time;
        printf("Finished child: %d, Tiempo: %f\n", finished, Load_time);            
    }

    return 0;
}

double getTime (int who){
    double usertime, systime;
    struct rusage usage;

    getrusage (who, &usage);

    usertime = (double) usage.ru_utime.tv_sec +
        (double) usage.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

    systime = (double) usage.ru_stime.tv_sec +
        (double) usage.ru_stime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

    return (usertime + systime);
}
```

With that argument the function can tell the total time used by the child process. Note that when called with RUSAGE_CHILDREN, the time in the `struct rusage usage` structure will be that of every children spawned by the parent (including grand children) that have been properly waited by their parent process.